# Is the loop body changing my call method? (NEWB)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am completely new to programming of any sort.  I am taking an introductory python class which requires the students to provide code for walking around a set of rooms.  I figured it would be a good idea to assign some dictionaries from the layouts and go from there.  When I try to call the value for the key on the first assignment of command it works as expected.  But when I do the same exact operations two lines later I get a type error.  I am stumped.

```
rooms = {
    'r1': {'name': 'Room1', 'north': 'room7', 'east': 'room2', 'item': 'ob1'},
    'r2': {'name': 'Room2', 'west': 'room1', 'item': 'ob2'},
    'r3': {'name': 'Room3', 'north': 'room4', 'west': 'room7', 'item': 'ob3'},
    'r4': {'name': 'Room4', 'south': 'room3', 'item': 'ob4'},
    'r5': {'name': 'Room5', 'east': 'room6', 'south': 'room7', 'item': 'ob5'},
    'r6': {'name': 'Room6', 'west': 'room5', 'item': 'ob6'},
    'r7': {'name': 'Room7', 'north': 'room5', 'east': 'room3', 'south': 'room1', 'west': 'room8', 'item': 'nothing'},
    'r8': {'name': 'Room8', 'east': 'room7', 'item': 'monster'}
}

location = rooms['r7']

command = input('You are in {}.  What would you like to do?: '.format(location['name']))#WORKS 
    #HERE
while True:
    command = input('You are in {}.  What would you like to do?: '.format(location['name']))#ERROR
    if command in location:
        location = command
        continue
    else:
        print('Invalid Input.  Please type a direction.')
```

Comment: You want `location = rooms[location[command]]`, not `location = command`.  Even with that, there are problems, because the keys are abbreviations, and your north/south/east/west elements are spelled out.  If you expand the abbreviations (`room7` instead of `r7`), then it starts to work.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including the full error message along with example input, expected output, and any actual output. You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fixed version of the code you have so far.

```
rooms = {
    'room1': {'name': 'Room1', 'north': 'room7', 'east': 'room2', 'item': 'ob1'},
    'room2': {'name': 'Room2', 'west': 'room1', 'item': 'ob2'},
    'room3': {'name': 'Room3', 'north': 'room4', 'west': 'room7', 'item': 'ob3'},
    'room4': {'name': 'Room4', 'south': 'room3', 'item': 'ob4'},
    'room5': {'name': 'Room5', 'east': 'room6', 'south': 'room7', 'item': 'ob5'},
    'room6': {'name': 'Room6', 'west': 'room5', 'item': 'ob6'},
    'room7': {'name': 'Room7', 'north': 'room5', 'east': 'room3', 'south': 'room1', 'west': 'room8', 'item': 'nothing'},
    'room8': {'name': 'Room8', 'east': 'room7', 'item': 'monster'}
}

location = rooms['room7']

while True:
    command = input(
        f"You are in {location['name']}.  What would you like to do?: "
    )
    if command in location:
        location = rooms[location[command]]
    else:
        print('Invalid Input.  Please type a direction.')
```

The `while` loop didn't really have anything to do with the problem.  The two major bugs were:

1. Your `rooms` dict doesn't use the room IDs consistently.  In order to be able to use a direction to look up the corresponding room, they need to refer to the rooms the same way.  I've normalized the `rooms` keys to use the `roomN` format that the rooms themselves use.
2. You need to correctly translate the direction into the next room.  This requires that you first get the room ID based on the combination of the current `location` and the `command`, and second that you get the next room from the `rooms` dict -- all together this is simply `rooms[location[command]]`.

Note that if the user types in "name" or "item" as the direction, your program will still crash!  I'd probably fix this by separating the directions from the others pieces of room data, so that it's not possible for your program to confuse the directions with the other information about the room.  For example:

```
from typing import Dict, List, NamedTuple


class Room(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    exits: Dict[str, str]  # map of direction to room ID
    items: List[str]


rooms = {
    'room1': Room('Room1', {'north': 'room7', 'east': 'room2'}, ['ob1']),
    'room2': Room('Room2', {'west': 'room1'}, ['ob2']),
    # etc
    'room7': Room('Room7', {'north': 'room5', 'east': 'room3', 'south': 'room1', 'west': 'room8'}, []),
    'room8': Room('Room8', {'east': 'room7'}, ['monster'])
}

location = rooms['room7']

while True:
    command = input(
        f"You are in {location.name}.  What would you like to do?: "
    )
    if command in location.exits:
        location = rooms[location.exits[command]]
    elif command == "look":
        print(f"Exits are {', '.join(location.exits.keys())}.")
        if location.items:
            print(f"There is {', '.join(location.items)} here.")
    elif command == "quit"
        print("Bye!")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input.  Please type a direction.")
        print(f"Exits from this room: {', '.join(location.exits.keys())}")
```

```
You are in Room7.  What would you like to do?: south
You are in Room1.  What would you like to do?: look
Exits are north, east.
There is ob1 here.
You are in Room1.  What would you like to do?: east
You are in Room2.  What would you like to do?: look
Exits are west.
There is ob2 here.
You are in Room2.  What would you like to do?: get ob2
Invalid Input.  Please type a direction.
Exits from this room: west
You are in Room2.  What would you like to do?:
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
location = command
```

You replace the `location` (a dictionary `room['r7']`) with the variable `command`, which is a string like `"north"`.

Then you go again in the while loop (`while True`) and you do:

```
format(location['name']))
```

At this point, `location` is a string and in Python you cannot slice a string like that.

I still not have clear what you want to achieve when doing

```
location = command
```